# Gremlin query to get all interconnected vertex value in javascript

Tags: javascript, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Can any one help me to figure out how to fetch content of all vertex which are connected each other in javascript , I need all the values of all vertex which are connected

For example in below diagram I have a business vertex and there are two outgoing edges from business  , what I need is all the contents of business vertex and video and image vertex

[graph look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPjA5.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Gremlin provides a variety of ways that you might be able to handle this as your description of the desired results was a bit vague.  However you will want to   use a combination of traversing steps (`out()` step), filtering steps (`has()`/`hasLabel()`) combined with the `path()` step to get the list of vertices and then return the data using `elementMap()`.  I have put a demonstration of this here:

https://gremlify.com/a78ox51u9os/1